# HtmlUnit Working with tables

Tags: java, htmlunit

I'm learning how to use htmlunit and found one problem when trying to get table element.
I'm using following Java code:

```
for (final HtmlTableRow row : table.getRows()) {
            System.out.println("Found row");
            for (final HtmlTableCell cell : row.getCells()) {
                System.out.println("   Found cell: " + cell.asText());
            }
        }
```

as it is described in htmlunit [web](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/table-howto.html) page. I'm trying to get element from code where elements are getting from `document.write()` function and as result I'm getting empty element. I've searched answers in Google but no result.

Comment: Found row
   Found cell: Connection status
   Found cell:
this is output and it must be 
Found row
   Found cell: Connection status
   Found cell: Connected

Comment: Can you tell me the URL you are working with?

Comment: i'm working with router url